# How to pass a callback function when sending a message from a webview to the extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm following the guide [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-a-webview-to-an-extension) to pass a message from my webview back to my extension. The message I would like to pass looks like this:

```
vscode.postMessage({
  'My_ID',
  {
    id: 123,
    callbackFn: () => { ...do something }
  }
});
```

What I would like to happen is this: when the extension receives the message, it does some processing and then executes the callback function (`callbackFn()`). When I try this, I see this error:

```
VM97:16 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': function callbackFn() {
 ...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
    at Object.postMessage (<anonymous>:16:15)
    at WebViewUtils.sendMessage (vscode-resource:/Users/user1/github/vscode-extension/dist/webviews/index.js:157158:19)
    ...
```